# retorno do firebase

Tags: angular

Galera, gostaria de ajuda com relação ao retorno do firebase, é o seguinte, no meu projeto angular tenho um componente com alguns campos a serem validados e um serviço somente para validações, estou tendo dificuldade de pegar um retorno como eu preciso, segue o código

meu componente formulario.ts tenho:

```
nextPage() {
if(this.serviceValidate.validaEmail(this.dataForm.value.gn_email)) {
   return;
 }
}
```

Em meu serviço de validação tenho ValidaUsuario.service.ts tenho:

```
  validaEmail(email: string): any {
let valida = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+\.)[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2,3}$/;
 //1º validação
if(email == '') {
  this.snackbar.openSnackBar('Campo email obrigatório');
  return false;

//2º validação
} else if(!valida.exec(email)) {
  this.snackbar.openSnackBar('Email não é valido, tento outro!');
  return false;
} 

// 3º validação
 var data =  this.db.list(this.PATH,
 ref => ref.orderByChild('gn_email')
           .equalTo(email))
           .valueChanges(); 
}
```

Se possível, gostaria de pegar um boolean nesta 3º validação, já testei duas maneiras
assim

```
var data =  this.db.list(this.PATH,
    ref => ref.orderByChild('gn_email')
               .equalTo(email))
               .valueChanges();
```

e assim :

```
   firebase.database().ref(this.PATH)
 .ref.orderByChild('gn_email')
 .equalTo(email)
 .on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
   console.log(snapshot.exists())
   var data = snapshot.exists();
// })
```

Como pegar o retorno sem fazer o subscribe no component ?

Comment: Pq vc não quer fazer o subscribe? Observables são lazy eles só rodam quando vc da o subscribe.

Comment: Eu estou tentando fazer uma validação no meu componente que tem um formulário e um campo email, por exemplo, fiz um serviço somente para validar o email, la tenho if email == email@example.com return true if email != '' return true e se if email == firebase(tabela.usuario.email) return true, não sei se consegui explicar

Comment: no servico tenho essas 3 validações se ele está no formato de email se não está vazio e se algum usuário no DATABASE não tem email igual, quero no componente pegar apenas true or false